# extract json with javascript preprocessing Zabbix

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath, zabbix

i'm trying to extrapolate a json if a string is contained. My json is this:

```
[
   {
      "name":"PE02S-PK00400_2002",
      "ip":"",
      "pk":0.4,
      "roadCode":"A32",
      "roadName":"A32",
      "roadDescription":"A32 TORINO-BARDONECCHIA",
      "directionName":"A32_DIR_A",
      "directionDescription":"BARDONECCHIA",
      "sectionName":"A32_DIR_A_SEZ1",
      "sectionDescription":"RIVOLI - SUSA",
      "laneName":null,
      "laneDescription":null,
      "tunnelName":"A32_GALLERY_LA_PEROSA",
      "tunnelDescription":"LA PEROSA",
      "idTecnico":"2002"
   },
   {
      "name":"PE04S-PK00500_2004",
      "ip":"",
      "pk":0.5,
      "roadCode":"A32",
      "roadName":"A32",
      "roadDescription":"A32 TORINO-BARDONECCHIA",
      "directionName":"A32_DIR_A",
      "directionDescription":"BARDONECCHIA",
      "sectionName":"A32_DIR_A_SEZ1",
      "sectionDescription":"RIVOLI - SUSA",
      "laneName":null,
      "laneDescription":null,
      "tunnelName":"A32_GALLERY_LA_PEROSA",
      "tunnelDescription":"LA PEROSA",
      "idTecnico":"2004"
   },
   {
      "name":"PE06S-PK00750_2006",
      "ip":"",
      "pk":0.75,
      "roadCode":"A32",
      "roadName":"A32",
      "roadDescription":"A32 TORINO-BARDONECCHIA",
      "directionName":"A32_DIR_A",
      "directionDescription":"BARDONECCHIA",
      "sectionName":"A32_DIR_A_SEZ1",
      "sectionDescription":"RIVOLI - SUSA",
      "laneName":null,
      "laneDescription":null,
      "tunnelName":"A32_GALLERY_LA_PEROSA",
      "tunnelDescription":"LA PEROSA",
      "idTecnico":"2006"
   }
]
```

The javascript script is this:

```
function (value) {
    var res = ''
    var json = JSON.parse(value)

    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

        if (json[i].name =~ "{HOST.NAME}") {

            res = JSON.stringify(json[i])

            return res
        }

    }

}
```

{HOST.NAME} is SOS-PE02S-PK00400

Everything works, except the field (name) is -1.

Here is the result:

```
{
   "name":-1,
   "ip":"",
   "pk":0.4,
   "roadCode":"A32",
   "roadName":"A32",
   "roadDescription":"A32 TORINO-BARDONECCHIA",
   "directionName":"A32_DIR_A",
   "directionDescription":"BARDONECCHIA",
   "sectionName":"A32_DIR_A_SEZ1",
   "sectionDescription":"RIVOLI - SUSA",
   "laneName":null,
   "laneDescription":null,
   "tunnelName":"A32_GALLERY_LA_PEROSA",
   "tunnelDescription":"LA PEROSA",
   "idTecnico":"2002"
}
```

Here is the result I would expect:

```
{
   "name":"PE02S-PK00400_2002",
   "ip":"",
   "pk":0.4,
   "roadCode":"A32",
   "roadName":"A32",
   "roadDescription":"A32 TORINO-BARDONECCHIA",
   "directionName":"A32_DIR_A",
   "directionDescription":"BARDONECCHIA",
   "sectionName":"A32_DIR_A_SEZ1",
   "sectionDescription":"RIVOLI - SUSA",
   "laneName":null,
   "laneDescription":null,
   "tunnelName":"A32_GALLERY_LA_PEROSA",
   "tunnelDescription":"LA PEROSA",
   "idTecnico":"2002"
}
```

I don't understand where is wrong. If you can help me I am grateful.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @SAM I would like to get the entire JSON.

Comment: It's already JS array.

Comment: @Reyno  
I want to know if my string is contained in the JSON name field and extract the json. Usage = ~

Comment: @SAM 
The problem is that I get the json, but the name field is set as -1. Why?

Comment: Answered Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is used for [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) but not for comparison.

`==` or `===`  for [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Since for loop starts perfectly but when it goes to `if` condition, first of all you're not checking for equality instead you are assigining to `json[i].name` which is the first element/object of `json` arrray to whatever `~"{HOST.NAME}"` returns which would be `-1(see the below snippet)`.

Then you `console.log` that object i.e `json[0]` and you're assigning the result of `JSON.stringify(json[i])` to `res` and return the result.

```js
console.log( ~"AnythingString" );
```

To check if some text includes in a string then you can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
const name = "marcombar";

const result = name.includes("bar");
console.log(result);
```

If you need to check/compare it with `json[i].name`

```js
const json = [{
    name: "PE02S-PK00400_2002",
    ip: "",
    pk: 0.4,
    roadCode: "A32",
    roadName: "A32",
    roadDescription: "A32 TORINO-BARDONECCHIA",
    directionName: "A32_DIR_A",
    directionDescription: "BARDONECCHIA",
    sectionName: "A32_DIR_A_SEZ1",
    sectionDescription: "RIVOLI - SUSA",
    laneName: null,
    laneDescription: null,
    tunnelName: "A32_GALLERY_LA_PEROSA",
    tunnelDescription: "LA PEROSA",
    idTecnico: "2002",
  },
  {
    name: "PE04S-PK00500_2004",
    ip: "",
    pk: 0.5,
    roadCode: "A32",
    roadName: "A32",
    roadDescription: "A32 TORINO-BARDONECCHIA",
    directionName: "A32_DIR_A",
    directionDescription: "BARDONECCHIA",
    sectionName: "A32_DIR_A_SEZ1",
    sectionDescription: "RIVOLI - SUSA",
    laneName: null,
    laneDescription: null,
    tunnelName: "A32_GALLERY_LA_PEROSA",
    tunnelDescription: "LA PEROSA",
    idTecnico: "2004",
  },
  {
    name: "PE06S-PK00750_2006",
    ip: "",
    pk: 0.75,
    roadCode: "A32",
    roadName: "A32",
    roadDescription: "A32 TORINO-BARDONECCHIA",
    directionName: "A32_DIR_A",
    directionDescription: "BARDONECCHIA",
    sectionName: "A32_DIR_A_SEZ1",
    sectionDescription: "RIVOLI - SUSA",
    laneName: null,
    laneDescription: null,
    tunnelName: "A32_GALLERY_LA_PEROSA",
    tunnelDescription: "LA PEROSA",
    idTecnico: "2006",
  },
];

function convert() {
  for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    const nameToCheck = "SOS-PE02S-PK00400";
    if (json[i].name.includes(nameToCheck)) {
      console.log("Equal");
      console.log(json[i]);
      res = JSON.stringify(json[i]);
      return res;
    } else {
      console.log("Not Equal");
    }
  }
}
convert();
```

Comment: updated answer. Accept the answer If I've helped you and answer what you want.

Comment: I would like to know if that string is contained in the name field, not if it is exactly the same.

Comment: not really. I would like to know if that string is contained in the name field, not if it is exactly the same.

I am trying this, but it doesn't work.

`var res = 0

var json = JSON.parse(value)
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
 const nameToCheck = "{HOST.NAME}";
 var name = JSON.stringify(json[i].name);
 if (nameToCheck.includes(name, 0)) {

  res = JSON.stringify(json[i]);
  return res;
 } else {
  return res;
 }
}`